# Redux connect in recursive React.Component

Tags: reactjs, recursion, redux, react-redux

I have created a recursive component that needs to access the Redux state so I created this:

```
class MyRecursiveComponent extends React.Component<MyRecursiveComponentProps>{
  constructor(props: MyRecursiveComponentProps) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {*/some State*/}
  }

...

  render(){
    if(Object.keys(this.props).includes('templates'))
    {
      return (<MyRecursiveComponent p={/*some Props*/}/>)
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state:any) => {
return {
  templates: state.templates
}
}

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps)
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>

export default connect(mapStateToProps,null)(MyRecursiveComponent )
```

The first time I call the component connect is working and I can access this.props.templates but as soon as I call it recursively it's not connecting any more.

Any hints?

The templates state can become quite large(1mb+) so I don't want to pass it as a parameter or do you think this wouldn't matter?

Regards Christian

Comment: Objects are passed as reference. So `1mb` state is still roughly `1mb` passed down multiple times.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this makes it way easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first time I call the component connect is working and I can access this.props.templates but as soon as I call it recursively it's not connecting any more.

The JSX inside of your component is calling the version which is **not** connected to the store.  You have a class `MyRecursiveComponent` which **is not** connected, and an unnamed `default export` which **is** connected.

@Sam R.'s comment is correct that in this case you should just pass down the `templates` (though be careful, because with the current `if(Object.keys(this.props).includes('templates'))` check, that would create an infinite loop!).

But if you do want to use a connected component within the same file, you need to assign it to a variable instead of just exporting it anonymously.  This would make sense if the `mapStateToProps` was dependent on `ownProps` such that different instances of your component selected different values from the state.

```
const MyConnectedRecursiveComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(MyRecursiveComponent);
export default MyConnectedRecursiveComponent;
```

Inside of `render`, you would use the connected version:

```
return (
    <MyConnectedRecursiveComponent p={/*some Props*/}/>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, will try it like this. Passing templates down should also work as this is only a part of the code and the data changes so no infinite loop should happen.

Comment: If your component doesn't need to access every template, you could use your `mapStateToProps` to select only the ones you need based on the component's props.